# how can I prove this equation from Binomial theorem??

Tags: binomial-theorem, partial-fractions

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{ {\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\  i\end{array}\right)} {(-1)^i}}{k+i} =  {\frac{1}{k\left(\begin{array}{c}k+n\\ k\end{array}\right)}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with binomial expansion
$$
(x-1)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right) (-1)^{n-i} x^{i}.
$$
$$
(x-1)^n x^{k-1} = \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right) (-1)^{n-i} x^{i+k-1}.
$$
Then integrate it from $0$ to $1$ and get
$$
(-1)^n B(n+1,k) = \int_{0}^1 (x-1)^n x^{k-1} dx = \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right) (-1)^{n-i} \frac{1}{k+i}.
$$
Now divide both sides by $(-1)^n$. This gives you a final result.

EDIT: Indeed, using porperties of $B$ and $\Gamma$ functions (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)) one can get
$$
B(n+1,k) = \frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(n+1+k)} = \frac{n! (k-1)!}{(n+k)!} = \frac{1}{k\left(\begin{array}{c}k+n\\ k\end{array}\right)}.
$$

Comment: so how should I reach  $${\frac{1}{k\left(\begin{array}{c}k+n\\ k\end{array}\right)}}$$

Comment: @AmirHosseinShekari I've edited my answer. I hope, clarifications will help.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: by residues or equivalent techniques it is not difficult to show that the function 
$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x+n)}=\frac{1}{(x)_{n+1}} $$
has the following partial fraction decomposition:
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{h=0}^{n}(-1)^h\binom{n}{h}\frac{1}{x+h} $$
from which it follows that
$$ \sum_{h=0}^{n}(-1)^h\binom{n}{h}\frac{1}{k+h} = n!\cdot f_n(k) = \frac{n!}{k(k+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k+n)} $$
as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\sum_{i = 0}^{n}
{{n \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i} \over k + i} = {1 \over k{k + n \choose k}}}:\ \ds{\large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}{{n \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i} \over k + i} & =
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}{n \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k + i - 1}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 1}\sum_{i = 0}^{n}{n \choose i}\pars{-t}^{i}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] & =
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t}
_{\ds{\mrm{B}\pars{k,n + 1}}} = {\Gamma\pars{k}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{k + n + 1}}
\end{align}

$\ds{B}$ is the
[Euler Beta Integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E1) which is written in [terms of the Gamma Function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E1) $\ds{\Gamma}$.

In addition,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}{{n \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i} \over k + i} & =
{\pars{k - 1}!\, n! \over \pars{k + n}!} =
{1 \over k}\,{1 \over \pars{k + n}!/\pars{k!\, n!}}
\\[3mm] & =
\bbox[15px,#ffc,border:1px groove navy]{\large 1 \over \large k{k + n \choose k}}
\end{align}